# Video appears smaller on Android 12 only

Tags: android, targetsdkversion

If you make an app that plays videos in full screen,
Sometimes videos appear smaller on Android 12 alone.

Is this a bug unique to Android 12?
Has anyone seen the same phenomenon?
[behavior Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tSmB0.png)

I use this library for video `org.videolan.android.libvlc-all`.

Android 13 didn't experience this.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.